# Iphone : Problem regarding image Stored in Document Directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In a App. i am saving the images from server in Document Directory.

In Database that images are came as "image4_12:19:27.png"

in documents directory folder that images stored as "image4_12/19/27.png"

How that image convert "image4_12:19:27.png" to  "image4_12/19/27.png" in Document Directory.

What should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the file name into parts separated by `:` and then later append them.

```
NSString * fileName = @"image4_12:19:27.png";
NSArray * components = [fileName componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSString * relativeFilePath = [components componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];
NSString * absoluteFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:components];
```

where `documentsDirectory` is the path to the documents directory.

Comment: Great, But How do i fetch image name from following string? `"/Users/taxsmart6/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/F47B24BB-B480-4154-A2EB-BA6B445B9455/Documents/image1_04:24:28.png";`

Comment: Say this is in `sourceFilePath`. Then `fileName = [sourceFilePath lastPathComponent];` should give you the file name.

Comment: `componentsSeparatedByString` it returns array.